# How to draw smooth circle in Libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to draw an circle to Libgdx which is created from Image not ShapeRenderer. But when I try to draw image to SpriteBatch it does not draw smoothly. 
[image: This is the Image that I am using]

[image: This is the Image that drawing]

I checked the image resolution and Image Dimension is 1673x1673 and Sprite Size is 80x80.

```
  //This is my GameState code
  @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        SpriteBatch sb = game.batch;
        Color bg = ThemeFactory.getInstance().getTheme().backgroundColor;
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(bg.r, bg.g, bg.b, bg.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        for(int i =0;i<elements.size();i++){
            if(!(elements.get(i) instanceof Arrow)){
                elements.get(i).render(sb);//HERE IS DRAWING HAPPENING
            }
        }
        sb.end();
        barriers.render(sb);
        renderHud();
    }
```

My circle constructor and rendering code is below.

```
public Circle(Texture texture, Size size, Vector3 position){
        mSprite = new Sprite(texture);
        mSprite.setSize(size.width, size.height);//80x80
        mSprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
        mSprite.setOriginCenter();
    }
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    mSprite.draw(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 tips:
1. Raise up sampling
2. use libgdx mipmap for your texture

I recommend using : filter 1: MipMapLinearNearest,Nearest  or filter 2: Linear,Linear

filter 1 is fast, filter 2 is high quality

for more info read [this](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403)

---

Filtering

The minification/magnification filters define how the image is handled upon scaling. For "pixel-art" style games, generally Filter.Nearest is suitable as it leads to hard-edge scaling without blurring. Specifying Filter.Linear will use bilinear scaling for smoother results, which is generally effective for 3D games (e.g. a 1024x1024 rock or grass texture) but not always so for a 2D game. In OpenGL, the terms used are GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I resolved my problem using MipMapLinearNearest,Nearest filter.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter in your texture.

Eg.

```
texture.setFilter (TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest );
```

For more information about filters, refer this blog: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

Comment: TextureFilter.Nearest is standard in Texture class. Not looking like he changed it.

Comment: It does not changed anything

Comment: Did you try the filter MipMapLinearNearest?